# Spoofing HTTP Request headers within javascript?

Tags: javascript, spoofing

Is it possible to spoof http request headers within javascript inside the client browser?

I was wondering whether it would be possible to modify the http request headers (such as HOSTS:) for sites that are using image pixel tracking.

Comment: what about these plugins : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/modify-headers/  and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

Comment: w/ajax some headers yes, some no. but for requests from <img>s, you don't have any direct header control.

Comment: What do you mean by "within Javascript"?

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely as this would be a serious security issue. However, as @elsadek suggests, it *might* be possible from a browser addin which has more access. Certainly not possible from in-page JavaScript.

However, in terms of blocking tracking pixels. The issue is, how do you know whether an image will be a tracking pixel image BEFORE you access it? Once your browser has issued the request for it, the server already has your details.